# How to randomly choose multiple keys and its value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have a dictionary like this:

```
user_dict = {
    user1: [(video1, 10), (video2, 20), (video3, 1)]
    user2: [(video1, 4), (video2, 8), (video6, 45)]
    ...
    user100: [(video1, 46), (video2, 34), (video6, 4)]                 
}
```

`(video1, 10)` means (videoid, number of request).

Now I want to randomly choose 10 users and do some calculation like

1. calculate number of videoid for each user.
2. sum up the number of requests for these 10 random users, etc.

Then I need to increase the random number to 20, 30, 40 respectively.

But `random.choice` can only choose one value at a time, right? How to choose multiple keys and the list following each key?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's what [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org//library/random.html?highlight=random.choice#random.sample) is for:

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

This can be used to choose the keys.  The values can subsequently be retrieved by normal dictionary lookup:

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(range(100))
>>> keys = random.sample(list(d), 10)
>>> keys
[52, 3, 10, 92, 86, 42, 99, 73, 56, 23]
>>> values = [d[k] for k in keys]
```

Alternatively, you can directly sample from `d.items()`.

Comment: If you wanted to get the keys and values, you could just use ``random.sample()`` on ``dict.items()``, rather than getting a key then doing a lookup.

Comment: you need list(d) or you will get this error
raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).

Comment: Note that this appears to have O(n) time complexity (in length of the dict) due to having to do list(d).

Comment: A faster approach is to sample from `dict.keys()`, which you can do without casting to a list. See eg the middle solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002638/2989201

Comment: Actually that is also O(n), the list-construction from `.keys()` iterator just happens internally in `random.sample()`

Comment: @zplizzi I don't think there is a way to make this O(k) for dictionaries. The internal structure used since Python 3.6 might allow this (not sure about this, have to double check), but the Python interface of the dictionary is not powerful enough to actually leverage that internal structure. In older versions of Python, it's not even possible with C code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah you are correct - although I think it's useful for people to know the time complexity of a solution, especially when it's something that seems like it could be constant-time but isn't. For anyone trying to find a simple constant-time solution, check out https://github.com/robtandy/randomdict (and the minor bug fixed in an open PR there).

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to return a dictionary, you could use a dictionary comprehension instead of the list comprehension in [Sven Marnach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125602/2514130) like so:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(range(100))
keys = random.sample(d.keys(), 10)
sample_d = {k: d[k] for k in keys}
```

Comment: Or just sample `d.items()`...... (like is mentioned is Sven's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
import random
mydict = {"a":"its a", "b":"its b"}
random.sample(mydict.items(), 1)

# [('b', 'its b')]
# or
# [('a', 'its a')]
```

Comment: This does not work in Python 3, you need list(mydict.values()).

Comment: this will do it to get key and value pairs:
`random.sample(mydict.items(), 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I have work on this problem,

```
import random

def random_a_dict_and_sample_it( a_dictionary , a_number ): 
    _ = {}
    for k1 in random.sample( list( a_dictionary.keys() ) , a_number ):
        _[ k1 ] = a_dictionary[ k1 ]
    return _
```

**In your case:**

```
user_dict = random_a_dict_and_sample_it( user_dict , 2 )
```