# Get a random sample of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, random, python-3.4

I'm working with a big dictionary and for some reason I also need to work on small random samples from that dictionary. How can I get this small sample (for example of length 2)?

Here is a toy-model:

```
dy={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
```

I need to perform some task on dy which involves all the entries. Let us say, to simplify, I need to sum together all the values:

```
s=0
for key in dy.key:
    s=s+dy[key]
```

Now, I also need to perform the same task on a random sample of dy; for that I need a random sample of the keys of dy. The simple solution I can imagine is

```
sam=list(dy.keys())[:1]
```

In that way I have a list of two keys of the dictionary which are somehow random. So, going back to may task, the only change I need in the code is:

```
s=0
for key in sam:
    s=s+dy[key]
```

The point is I do not fully understand how dy.keys is constructed and then I can't foresee any future issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example of:

```
dy = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
```

Then the sum of all the values is more simply put as:

```
s = sum(dy.values())
```

Then if it's not memory prohibitive, you can sample using:

```
import random

values = list(dy.values())
s = sum(random.sample(values, 2))
```

Or, since `random.sample` can take a `set`-like object, then:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import random

s = sum(itemgetter(*random.sample(dy.keys(), 2))(dy))
```

Or just use:

```
s = sum(dy[k] for k in random.sample(dy.keys(), 2))
```

An alternative is to use a `heapq`, eg:

```
import heapq
import random

s = sum(heapq.nlargest(2, dy.values(), key=lambda L: random.random()))
```

Comment: why not just creating a list via random.sample? what's the advantage in the use of itemgetter?

Comment: @user2988577 `itemgetter` can sometimes be quicker - otherwise - just write it as `sum(dy[k] for k in random.sample(dy.keys(), 2))`

Answer (score 9):

```
def sample_from_dict(d, sample=10):
    keys = random.sample(list(d), sample)
    values = [d[k] for k in keys]
    return dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `range(10)` with some randome sample from numphy

`{v:rows[v] for v in [list(rows.keys())[k] for k in range(10)]}`

Answer (score 0):

This should be quicker than creating a new dict and checking if the keys are part of the sample:

```
import random    
sample_n = 1000
output_dict = dict(random.sample(input_dict.items(), sample_n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@J-Mourad's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59830473/711006), but using a dictionary comprehension:

```
def sample_from_dict(d, n=10):
    keys = random.sample(list(d), n)
    return {k: d[k] for k in keys}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
origin_dict =  {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
sample_rate = 0.3
random_keys = random.sample(list(origin_dict.keys()), int(sample_rate * len(origin_dict)))
random_values = [origin_dict[k] for k in random_keys]

sample_dict = dict(zip(random_keys, random_values))
```

output:

```
{'d': 4, 'c': 3}
```